# Is it possible to execute a loop inside an object declaration in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I am creating a quiz with multiple choice questions. The questions and answers are loaded from an external xml file. The number of answer options is not consistent. It can vary. I am loading the data from the xml file and convert it to a global JSON object that the quiz app can access. Is there a way to loop through the answers inside the `answers` object declaration? The entire object currently looks like this (note that `currentQuestion` is a variable reference to the xml that's being read from):

```
var questionAnswerContentObject = {
    question: {
      questionTitle: currentQuestion.find("questionTitle").text(),
      questionBody: currentQuestion.find("questionBody").text()
    },
    answers: {
      // this is where the answers are supposed to go. 
      // the loop is just dummy test code. it fails with "Parsing error: Unexpected token ("
      for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
        answer: i;
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: it is a good question can you give sample of your app with html content

Comment: @GNETODOMINIQUE: What would the HTML add to the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional answers after your object initialization using an array. You can then use your for loop to dynamically add answers afterwards after reading your XML file. Your object can be setup like:

```
answer : {
    [
        answer1: {
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to loop through the answers inside the answers object declaration?

No, you can't

---

**What you can do is create a function and initialize those attributes.**

- To initialize the attribute answers, you can use [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to set the necessary array of answers.

```js
var questionAnswerContentObject = function() {
  this.question = {
    questionTitle: "title",
    questionBody: "body"
  };

  this.answers = (function() {
    // this is where the answers are supposed to go. 
    // the loop is just dummy test code. it fails with "Parsing error: Unexpected token ("
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      array.push(i);
    }
    
    return array;
  })();
};

var questionObject = new questionAnswerContentObject()
console.log(questionObject);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Beautiful. I notice that you use "this." I know that it refers to the object that an operation is performed on but have not used that in any of my object declarations and have not encountered any errors. Is that merely a best practice or is there a purpose for using it inside object declarations?

Comment: @GuybrushThreepwood it's necessary to set that attribute the object, otherwise, those attributes would be simply local variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
 var questionAnswerContentObject  = {};

questionAnswerContentObject.question.questionTitle = currentQuestion.find("questionTitle").text();

questionAnswerContentObject.answer = [];
for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
 var ans = currentQuestion.find(i).text();
questionAnswerContentObject.answer.push(ans);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this directly, as long as you have access to the original items list of answers.  You can't use a `for`-loop directly inside an object literal.  But you can use a `map` statement.

So I'm imagining the scenario where you can get access to the answers as an array, similar to how you get the title (`currentQuestion.find("questionTitle").text()`), perhaps `currentQuestion.find("questionAnswers").values()`.  Then you can simply `map` over the results inside your literal:

```js
// This is just a dummy implementation.  Don't know what the real one would look like
const currentQuestion = {
  questionTitle: 'Why?',
  questionBody: 'What is the meaning of life?',
  questionAnswers: ['Love', '42', 'Mu'],
  find: (prop) => ({text: _ => currentQuestion[prop],
                    values: _=> currentQuestion[prop]})
}

const questionAnswerContentObject = {
    question: {
      questionTitle: currentQuestion.find("questionTitle").text(),
      questionBody: currentQuestion.find("questionBody").text()
    },
    answers: currentQuestion.find("questionAnswers").values().map(i => ({answer: i}))
};

console.log(questionAnswerContentObject)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  this script .I hope it will help you .

```
var quiz = {
        question1:"what is a function ?",
        question2:"what is polymorphysm ",
        question3:"List two javascript framework",
        question4:"what php is used for?",
        question5:"is Java multy threaded ?",
        quiz1:["to make code better","to arrange your program","a function is a reusable block  of code which you can use  in your program"],
        quiz2 :["to format your code","it is not necessary in programming","in objet oriented programming polymorphysim is the ability of an object to take on many form..."],
        quiz3:["django ,express","symphony ,ruby on rail"," jquery , angular"],
        quiz4:["doing some front programming","a program language to computer operating system ","php is used to built web site and interact with database..."],
        quiz5:["no because it improve complexity","yes , each thread cannot run code concurrently","yes in multy threaded program each can handle different task at the same time"],
        displayQuiz: (question)=>{

            switch(question){
                case "question1": console.log("Q1 : " + quiz.question1);
                    for (i=0 ; i< quiz.quiz1.length ;i++){  console.log( (i +1) + ") "+ quiz.quiz1[i]);} 
                    break;
                case "question2":  console.log("Q2 : " + quiz.question2);
                    for (i=0 ; i< quiz.quiz1.length ;i++){  console.log( (i +1) + ") "+ quiz.quiz2[i]);} 
                    break;
                case "question3": console.log("Q3 : " +quiz.question3);
                    for (i=0 ; i< quiz.quiz1.length ;i++){  console.log( (i +1) + ") "+ quiz.quiz3[i]);} 
                    break;
                case "question4": console.log("Q4 : " +quiz.question4);
                    for (i=0 ; i< quiz.quiz1.length ;i++){  console.log( (i +1) + ") "+ quiz.quiz4[i]);} 
                    break;
                case "question5": console.log("Q5 : " +quiz.question5);
                    for (i=0 ; i< quiz.quiz1.length ;i++){  console.log( (i +1) + ") "+ quiz.quiz5[i]);} 
                    break;
            }
        },
        findAnswer:(question)=>{

            switch(question){
                case "question1":  console.log( quiz.question1);
                    console.log("a function is a reusable block  of code which you can in your program ");
                    break;
                case "question2": console.log( quiz.question2); 
                    console.log("in objet oriented programming polymorphysim is the ability of an object to take on many form...");
                    break;
                case "question3": console.log(quiz.question3);
                    console.log(" jquery, angular...");
                    break;
                case "question4": console.log(quiz.question4);
                    console.log("php is used to built web site and interact with database...");
                    break;
                case "question5": console.log(quiz.question5);
                    console.log("yes in multy threaded program each can handle different task at the same time");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

To display a  quiz questions of question 1 : `quiz.displayQuiz("question1")`

To find its right answer : `quiz.findAnswer("question1")`

> NB :Don t forget to notify me for potential errors .To be run on console